# Prevent monitors from going to sleep in lock screen on GNOME

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, displayport

I have two monitors running on my Fedora 22 machine, however due to [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1179924) sometimes the second monitor will not wake up after the computer goes to sleep, requiring me to unplug the DisplayPort cable and plug it back it after a few seconds.

I can set GNOME to never put my screens to sleep, however I cannot simply leave my computer unlocked all of the time when I'm not at my desk, so I'm curious if I can have my computer be locked, but the screens not go to sleep?

I'm using Fedora Workstation 22 with GNOME Shell 3.16.2.

Comment: It looks like if I lock the computer then jiggle the mouse, the screen stays on.  But this isn't really a solution but more of a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `slock` (apt-get install suckless-tools) which does not put the display to sleep. You'll need `xautolock` if you want to run it automatically.

**Note**: as Kevin Cox points out in the comments, this is less secure than using the GNOME lock screen because if it stops for any reason (crash, out of memory, sysreq) your desktop will be unlocked.

Comment: Note that this is less secure than using the GNOME lock screen because if it stops for any reason (crash, out of memory, sysreq) your desktop will be unlocked.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, that's a very good point. I've edited my answer to include it.